# I want to write a summary query and present the results in a single table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I need to write a summary report on 3 different status values, with a count and an amount column for each status, with the results presented in a single table.  For example, the output would look like this:

[image]

The query to produce each line of code (in an individual output) is:

```
select case when status_key = '2' then 'Paid' else '' end as 'Status'
, COUNT(BillNo) as [Count]
, SUM(amtpd) as [Amount Paid]
from billtable 
where client = 101
and status_key = '2'
group by status_key

select case when status_key = '1' then 'Queued' else '' end as 'Status'
, COUNT(BillNo) as [Count]
, SUM(amtpd) as [Amount Paid]
from billtable 
where client = 101
and status_key = '1'
group by status_key

select case when status_key = '4' then 'Hold' else '' end as 'Status'
, COUNT(BillNo) as [Count]
, SUM(amtpd) as [Amount Paid]
from billtable 
where client = 101
and status_key = '4'
group by status_key
```

This produces three results like:

[image]

I am using SQL Server database and SSMS to develop the query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for union.

Use WHERE to filter to only the status_keys that you want, then expand you CASE statement to re-code from a number to a word.

```
select
  case when status_key = '2' then 'Paid'
       when status_key = '1' then 'Queued'
       when status_key = '4' then 'Hold'
                             else 'Error!' end     AS [Status],
  COUNT(BillNo)                                    AS [Count],
  SUM(amtpd)                                       AS [Amount Paid]
from
  billtable
where
  client = 101
  AND status_key IN ('1','2','4')
group by
  status_key
```

**EDIT** Modified example using a dimension table

```
select
  status.description                                    AS [Status],
  COUNT(bill_table.BillNo)                              AS [Count],
  SUM(bill_table.amtpd)                                 AS [Amount Paid]
from
  billtable
inner join
  status
    on billtable.status_key = status.key
where
      bill_table.client      = 101
  AND bill_table.status_key IN ('1','2','4')
group by
  status.description
```

You can then have a foreign key constraint from `status` to `billtable`.  This will ensure that data can not be inserted into `billtable` unless there is a corresponding key in `status`.

Your lookups will then always work.  But at the 'cost' of inserts failing if the `status` table has not been correctly populated.

This `fact-table` and `dimension-table` construction is the underpinning of relational database design.

Comment: Thanks Dems.  The only difficulty with using CASE is that if there is not a value for one of the statements, I wouldn't get the category listed.

Comment: @JerryC - You should really have a table that translates the values from a number to a word. But then what if that lookup table is missing a relevant row? That's what foreign keys are for. It prohibits data from existing in the fact table *(`billtable`)* if the identifier doesn't exist in the dimension table *(a new `status` table)*.

Answer (score 1):

you just have to union all

```
your first query
Union all
your Second query
union all
your third query
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add UNION between your queries.

Comment: Thank you.  As I mentioned in @TlmaK0 comment, I used Union and it worked.  For some reason it escaped me at the initial glance.

Comment: @Jerry C.In this instance, I strongly advise you to use Dems' solution, not UNION. It's neater, shorter, easier to maintain etc etc., and one day you won't regret it!

Comment: Thanks for the input @Vinny Roe. I will take a look at it and see which works best.  I went on and placed each of the original queries in CTEs so just performed the UNION on the CTEs.  As I think about it, I will hand this off to one of my interns and let them make a recommendation.